# What is the difference between civil liberty and personal liberty?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, difference

Can anyone help me understand the differences in the meaning of civil liberty and personal liberty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personal liberty  Dictionary.com

> noun
>   1. the liberty of an individual to do his or her will freely except for those restraints imposed by law to safeguard the physical, moral,
>   political, and economic welfare of others.

and: Civil liberties

> Civil liberties or personal freedoms are personal guarantees and
>   freedoms that the government cannot abridge, either by law or by
>   judicial interpretation, without due process.  Wikipedia

I'd say they are fundamentally the same.

Comment: hmm. That is what I was also thinking but these political science term has some minute differences, because sometimes dictionary meanings do not capture the meaning in general use.

Comment: I am fairly certain and English is my first language, but others may well know better, so let's see if you get any other answers.